# How do you say, "I will remember you", or "I will never forget you," in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm trying to write a letter to a friend in Latin, but I do not trust google translate. Help?

Comment: The common words for remembering and forgetting are actually quite weird in Latin, so the grammar here won't be straightforward: I wouldn't trust Google Translate at all on this.

Answer (score 12):

### I will not/never forget you = *nōn/numquam tuī oblīviscar*

(The marks above the vowels are optional; they mark a pronunciation difference that disappeared in later Latin.)

- "I" is usually omitted in Latin, unless you want your identity to be very emphatic. The verb form makes it unambiguous without an extra word.
- *nōn* is "not", plain and simple.
- *numquam* is "never". Either one works here.
- *tuī* is the genitive singular of *tu*, "you". (This is a weird verb that takes the genitive when referring to people.)
- *oblīviscar* is the first singular future deponent indicative of *oblīviscor*, "to forget about". (The *r* at the end looks passive, but this verb uses passive forms with an active meaning.)

### I will (always) remember you = *(semper) tuī meminerō*

- *semper* is "always".
- *tuī*, as above, because this is another of those rare verbs which take the genitive.
- *meminerō* is, weirdly enough, in the *future perfect* tense: the verb *meminī* "to remember" doesn't have a normal future tense (or a present tense, for that matter), so the future perfect is used in its place.

Answer (score 12):

I find *memor* to be rather evocative, so here's another straightforward translation:

> **Semper memor ero tui.**

Rough translation:

> I will always be mindful of you.

"Mindful" is a decent stand-in, though as far as I'm aware *memor* doesn't have the additional "watchful" meaning.

Comment: (You might add the literal translation, if you can come up with a good English adjective for "memor".)